# SSH a Ubuntu Server with external ip

Tags: server, openssh

I have a Ubuntu server set up at my house and I am able to connect to it using SSH with its local IP.

How can I connect to it from anywhere with its external ip?

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings and port forwarding in your router?

Comment: My firewall allows the ssh port, but I don't think I've port forwarded yet.

Comment: Then there you go that is the solution ;)

Comment: And if your local network is behind a router, then you need to configure your router to allow the passage on port forwarding 22 to your ip address (local address 192.168.xxx.xxx).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take it the long way, which is what I usually do.. ;)

- Do you have a static IP for your router/internet connection? If not, use a dynamic IP provider.
- If you can answer the first question with "yes", go on and check your router for port forwarding
- Does your machine accept connections from external IPs ? -Check your IP-Tables

That should pretty much sum it up..

:)

Comment: I will try that later. I do have a static IP. Its connected to a separate router right next to the machine.